# How to remove space between footer

Tags: html, css

I've got CSS issue with footer on my webpage. I've used [this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page), but I've got empty space between footer and bottom of the page. Since there is no content in the body of my page the empty space is still here and there is an additional scrollbar when it's not needed. I really don't know why it's there. I've cleaned the CSS so there isn't any irrelevant code.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <p>
                Header Content
            </p>
            <hr>
        </div>
<div id="body">
    Body Content
</div>
        <div id="footer"><p id="copy">Copyright 2013</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
body { 
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
     }

#copy {vertical-align: bottom;text-align:center;font-family:Century Schoolbook;color:#8B0B04;font-size:14px;}
#footer {bottom: 0;width:100%;position: absolute;height: 60px}
#container {min-height: 100%;position: relative}
#body {padding-bottom: 60px}
```

My browser is Firefox, but in Chrome this doesn't work too. I will be so happy if you will give me any feedback and help. Thanks!

EDIT: I've posted something wrong imho. I will post the whole page next day. Again thanks for feedback.

Comment: Can you put it **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**? Also, which space you talking about?

Comment: `padding-bottom: 60px;` + `height: 100%;` what you expect?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be extra space at the bottom:  http://tinker.io/2b37d

Comment: Yh, on mine as well it doesn't :/

Comment: You might find this technique for sticky footers to be better than absolute positioning, since you don't have to know the height of the footer in advance:  http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

Comment: Sorry for making people's inn here waiting, I will upload the code to jsFiddle next day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` for container for removing the scroller

```
#container {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

and `padding-bottom` for body div

```
#body{
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

[Demo](http://tinker.io/2b37d/2) and here is [Demo](http://tinker.io/2b37d/3) with content

Comment: This will work only when there's no content, but on another pages I will have some content.

Comment: @albru13 I have updated my answer for case of if you have content on another page. Try this

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this, it's pretty simple and works. Tried all solutions here, but IMHO only this works. Thanks Sachin!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this css instead of what you have up there:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#copy {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Century Schoolbook;
    color:#8B0B04;
    font-size:14px;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative
}
```

Comment: removing the padding from <p> elements would solve that, but might not be what the OP wants

Comment: It will work, but I've tried that before started this thread and it's not well on my website.